# Laravel 8 - How to use if else condition inside for loop in seeder file?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-seeder

I'm new to Laravel. I've made a seeder file, and there is a for loop in it. I want to set the room_type based on the $i value, but it does not work.

This is the seeder file:

```
<?php

namespace Database\Seeders;

use Illuminate\Database\Console\Seeds\WithoutModelEvents;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class RoomTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run(): void
    {
        for($i=0;$i<15;$i++) {

            \App\Models\Room::create([
                "room_type" =>
                    if($i == 4){"single_bed"}elseif($i == 9){"twin_bed"}else{"third_bed"}, //It doesn't work.
                }
                "status"    =>  0]);
        }   
    }
}
```

This is the error I get:

```
   ParseError 

  syntax error, unexpected token "if"

  at database/seeders/RoomTableSeeder.php:19
     15▕         for($i=0;$i<15;$i++) {
     16▕ 
     17▕             \App\Models\Room::create([
     18▕                 "room_type" =>
  ➜  19▕                     if($i == 4){"single_bed"}elseif($i == 9){"twin_bed"}else{"third_bed"},
     20▕                 }
     21▕                 "status"    =>  0]);
     22▕         }   
     23▕     }

      +1 vendor frames 

  2   [internal]:0
      Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader::loadClass()
      +7 vendor frames 

  10  database/seeders/DatabaseSeeder.php:15
      Illuminate\Database\Seeder::call()
```

Comment: There are _tons_ of ways to accomplish this... You can define the variable in an `if()` statement **before** your Array, like `if ($i === 4) { $roomType = 'single_bed'; } else if ($i === 9) { $roomType = 'twin_bed'; } else { $roomType = 'third_bed'; }` then use it later as `'room_type' => $roomType`, or a Ternary `'room_type' => $i === 4 ? 'single_bed' ? ($i === 9 ? 'twin_bed' : 'third_bed')` (not recommended since it is nested), or a [`match()` expression](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.match.php) etc. The way you're using an `if()` inside of an array Key/Value is not valid.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to go this way, you can use an immediately invokeable function as the expression value.

I've used `match` here as opposed to several `if` statements for readability.

```
"room_type" => (function ($i) {
   return match ($i) {
       4 => "single_bed",
       9 => "twin_bed"
       default => "third_bed"
   }
})($i)
```

Comment: Very nice  I was gonna post the same thing with [`match(true) { ... }`](https://3v4l.org/Pkf41), but this is a little more concise (although you do have an extra `function ()`)